# Let $\{X_t\}$ be a stochastic process such that $\mathbb{E}(X_t)=3$ and $R_X(t,s)=5+e^{\frac{1}{2}|t-s|}$.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_t\}$ be a stochastic process such that $\mathbb{E}(X_t)=3$ and $R_X(t,s)=5+e^{\frac{1}{2}|t-s|}$. Find the mean, variance and covariance of $X_2$ and $X_5$.

I know that for all $t$, $\mathbb{E}(X_t)=3$, so $\mathbb{E}(X_2)=\mathbb{E}(X_5)=3$. On the other hand, $Var(X_t)=\mathbb{E}(X^{2}_t)-\mathbb{E}(X_t)^2=R_X(t,t)-(3)^2=5+e^{\frac{1}{2}|t-t|}-9<0$. What mistake am I making? I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Your observation is correct. There cannot be any process with these properties.

Comment: Sometimes the EE literature can define $R_{x}(t,s)$ somewhat differently so I would make sure the definition of it is what you think it is. Just a guess.